# Transposing data from column to row using references

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transpose, formulas, array-formulas

I have some data in a row, say A1 to Z1, and I would like to link to this data in another spreadsheet. However I would like to transpose it so the data runs from A1 to A26. It is important that it is linked in some type of function so that if I change the data on the first sheet, the second sheet is updated as well.

I'm thinking of some type of formula that states that as you go down a cell in column A, it knows to grab the data from the next cell to the right in Row 1. So: A2=B1; A3=C1; A4=D1 ...

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a specific problem that you are running in to? As it stands, your question seems to be just looking for confirmation that your idea would work. Why not try it on your own first and then, if you have problems, come back and show us what you tried and what didn't work with it.

Comment: Please reopen, this question. It is asking for a formula like plenty of other questions here do. I found a thorough explanation of the options here (transpose, indirect, address ...): https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/03/06/transpose-excel-rows-columns/#transpose-excel-formulas